# Order ParseQuery results by value in includeKey class

Tags: objective-c, parse-platform, pfquery, pfobject

I have 2 PFObjects - a Player let's say, and PlayerStats. There are also several other PFObjects associated with a PFPlayer.

I want to list the Players with the highest scores. The score is contained in PlayerStats.

Now I've tried:

```
PFQuery *andQuery = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Player"];
[andQuery includeKey:@"playerStats"]; 
PFQuery *statsQuery = [PlayerStats query];
[statsQuery orderByDescending:@"score"];
[andQuery whereKey:@"miniStats" matchesQuery:statsQuery];
```

But this doesn't appear to respect the order that the stats are returned in. What I really want to do is order my andQuery by a value in its included class.

I've tried running a basic query and ordering the results afterwards, however I have over 999 players, which is the limit of a PFQuery, so that doesn't help.

I suspect I have to do 2 levels of PFQuery - one for PlayerStats, in order, and then on the results of that query, submit another query using the objectIds of the players to get the Player objects. But this seems cumbersome, especially if I'm only searching for 20 results at a time say.

Ideally there would be something like:

```
[andQuery orderByDescending:@"playerStats.score"];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We wish, but no, not supported.  The only approach is to sort the result.  At least [underscorejs](http://underscorejs.org/#sortBy) is concise and awesome...

```
var _ = require('underscore');

PFQuery *andQuery = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Player"];
[andQuery includeKey:@"playerStats"];
andQuery.find().then(function(players) {
    players = _.sortBy(players, function(player) {
        return player.get("playerStats").get("score");
    });
});
```

**EDIT** - I should have mentioned initially:  if PlayerStat has a pointer to Player (which would be sensible), then you can do the query on stats for things like the all-time high score...

```
PFQuery *andQuery = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"PlayerStat"];
[andQuery includeKey:@"user"];
[andQuery descending:@"score"];
```

And at least the dot notation works for sub-subordinate keys (3 deep is the max)...

```
[andQuery includeKey:@"user.somePointerOnUser"];
```

As with all queries, these are limited to a max of 1000.

Comment: Great sorting, but still limited to 1000 results of PFQuery. I suppose at least these 1000 will be the most recently updated...

Comment: Yes.  Please see edit.  As an alternative, consider using a pointer back to user from the other classes.

Answer (score 0):

You declared statsQuery and use miniStatsQuery.

Why not store a Player pointer on each PlayerStats object, and then you can query for the sorted PlayerStats and include the Player key?

Comment: Ah fixed that - was a typo, as didn't copy paste directly. I can do that, however, I will still need to run a second query on the Player objects, as they include more PFObjects that I need returned...